# Generating an Entity Framework model - There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, model

I'm just trying to right click then select "Generate Model from database." and I get the error:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:
>
> 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
> exception for details.
>
> There is insufficient system memory in
> resource pool 'internal' to run this query. '.
>
> Loading metadata from
> the database took 00:00:04.0661492. Generating the model took
> 00:00:01.7104861.

I'm running SQL Server 2008 express, and only trying to generate 10 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in SQL Server and they have fixed it. Try [downloading the fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982854).

Answer (score 1):

Temporary fix :

> Go to `services.msc` and **stop and start** `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` and you are good to go!

Comment: Worked for me! great thanks. I just needed solution for development server. Production server was working just fine. Thanks once again.